# Delay function not working with ESP32

Tags: esp32

For whatever reason the delay function is not working (it is not delaying at all) with my ESP32 development board. Has anyone come across a similar issue before? It's not working with other sketches, in either the loop or set up functions. A sample sketch:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BNO055.h>
#include <utility/imumaths.h>
#include <BleMouse.h>

// mouse object
BleMouse ble("test", "me");

/** I2C pins **/
#define I2C_SDA 33
#define I2C_SCL 32

// I2C object
TwoWire wire_custom = TwoWire(0);

// Sensor object
Adafruit_BNO055 bno = Adafruit_BNO055(55, 0x28, &wire_custom);

/**************************************************************************/
function definitions
...

/**************************************************************************/
void setup(void)
{
  wire_custom.begin(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL, 400000);

  Serial.begin(115200);

  ble.begin();

  if (!bno.begin())
  {
    Serial.print("Ooops, no BNO055 detected ... Check your wiring or I2C ADDR!");
    while (1);
  }
  delay(1000);
  bno.setExtCrystalUse(true);

  // updating range
  bno.setMode(Adafruit_BNO055::OPERATION_MODE_CONFIG);
  delay(1000);
  write_register (0x28, 0x0A, 0b00111010);
  bno.setMode(Adafruit_BNO055::OPERATION_MODE_NDOF);
  delay(10000);
  byte result = read_register (0x28, 0x0A, 1);
  Serial.print(result);
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.print("\n");
}

/**************************************************************************/
void loop(void)
{
  sensor_calibration ();

  sensor_data (x_placeholder, y_placeholder);

  transform_sensor_data (x_placeholder, y_placeholder, x, y);

  if (ble.isConnected()) {
    ble.move(x, y);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Not delaying at all? Delaying forever? Too short a delay? Too long a delay? And what makes you believe that `delay()` is at fault?

Comment: how do you know that the delay function does not work? ... you do not have any debugging code that would verify that

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify it is not delaying at all regardless of what amount I set it to.

Comment: How would you know? The `loop()` in the above code doesn't use a delay, and has no output either.

Comment: The output is the last function which moves the mouse, and that begins immediately after uploading the code. So there is no delay between uploading the code and when the loop function starts running.

Comment: Gotta be something to do with that register you set, or the setcrystal thing or one of those libraries.  To prove it, just upload a dead simple delay sketch and see if it works then.

Comment: Yeah will have to do it, I'm actually sorry I posted this question without considering it fully yesterday. It was quite a stressful day with this as the cherry on top.